# Is it possible to make a binary tree without OOP in Python?

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

What I mean by OOP is basically the use of Class Node and stuff like this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/

I've searched for this but I only found how to iterate through a binary tree with non-recursive methods. So now I'm doubting about if a binary tree can be done without objetcs in Python.
One approach I tested was to create multiple nested lists, where each item was a node, and each item inside the node was another list (or node). Something like this:

```
t = [[root], [left], [right]]
```

Now I can append the other nodes to each one of these nodes

```
t[0][0].append(t2)
t[0][1].append(t3)
```

But I would have to guess how many dimensions will the tree have and I would end up with something like t[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] to get the data from certain node. I don't know how to do that, and I'm a total noob on Python. I'm used to C, but I have to help someone with their assingment, and they don't know OOP. Will they have to just learn OOP or is there another way to implement a binary tree in Python?

Comment: *Everything* in Python is an object, including lists and integers. But yes, you can build a binary tree with using just the built-in types, same as you could do in, say, C. How would *you* do this in C?

Comment: How come? In C I can make structs, but is there anything here to do that?

Comment: Take a look at [`namedtuple`](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/namedtuple.html).

Comment: Did you know that the Python types, in C, are just structs and functions? I'm not sure why you wouldn't use a Python class for the same here. But if you insist, look for dictionaries.

Comment: @anonymous: a `namedtuple` is immutable. You could use `._replace()` to alter individual fields, but that wouldn't update references to the same object. Not suitable for a tree implementation, really, as you'd have to update the parent node recursively up to the root to be able to change anything.

Comment: If you're helping someone with their assignment, and their assignment is to implement a binary tree, they're probably *supposed* to know OOP. You can do it without defining classes, but it's a lot more awkward.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He just want to create a tree. At the time of creation of node, he knows whether it has left/right child or not (though depends on the algorithm). But yes you are right about the *immutable* part and is worth mentioning

Comment: Really, a Python class, at its most basic (ignoring inheritance), is just the same as a C struct with the functions that operate on the struct bundled in, so you don't have to explicitly pass in the struct (that's the `self` parameter). This is an excellent time to dip your toe into the water here.

Comment: Alright I'll look for dictionaries. Thanks. Also, no, they aren't supposed to know OOP.

Comment: @Sebasuraa: they don't need to understand OOP just to build a simple class with attributes. There is no inheritance here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah I understand that, but the thing is... they are on an introductory programming course, and they haven't seen classes in their lectures. That's why I'm wondering this... maybe the teacher knew a way to do it without classes, or maybe they are supposed to learn them by their own.

Comment: Note that by using a dict you swap the indices for names, that's all. You would use a *loop* to traverse the tree, not `tree[0][0][0]` or `tree['left']['left']['left']`. You'd not use `node->left->left->left->left` in C either, would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple binary tree using a `dict`. I've only implemented an `insert` and a `traverse` function, but that's enough to use the tree for sorting.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from random import shuffle

D, L, R = 'data', 'left', 'right'

def insert(tree, data):
    if tree is None:
        tree = {D: data, L: None, R: None}
    elif data <= tree[D]:
        tree[L] = insert(tree[L], data)
    else:
        tree[R] = insert(tree[R], data)
    return tree

def traverse(tree):
    if tree is not None:
        for data in traverse(tree[L]):
            yield data
        yield tree[D]
        for data in traverse(tree[R]):
            yield data

a = list(range(32))
shuffle(a)
print(*a)

tree = None
for i in a:
    tree = insert(tree, i)

print(*traverse(tree))
```

**typical output**

```
28 0 14 3 27 15 11 31 19 5 9 22 13 2 20 30 1 8 10 26 18 25 24 6 21 23 7 4 12 29 17 16
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

This code will run on Python 2 or 3, but on recent versions of Python 3 the `traverse` function can be written more compactly:

```
def traverse(tree):
    if tree is not None:
        yield from traverse(tree[L])
        yield tree[D]
        yield from traverse(tree[R])
```